# Dart: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<String>

Tags: dart, async-await, typeerror

I'm experimenting a bit with async methods but I'm having a hard time.

I would like to implement some code whose goal is to simply return a string after waiting 2 seconds.

This is my first attempt and related error

```dart
String setUserDecision() {
    return 'Yes'; 
}

Future<String> fetchUserDecision() async {
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), setUserDecision());
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print("Fetching user role...");
  String decision = await fetchUserDecision();
  print('The user decision is: $decision');
  print("Done");
}
```

```
Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<String> Function()?'.
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), setUserDecision());
```

I can't understand the error, I may think the String type is not right, but I don't understand how to change it. I also tried this solution, thinking it might make sense (maybe), but nothing.

```dart
Future<String> setUserDecision() async{
    return await 'Yes'; 
}

Future<String> fetchUserDecision() async {
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), setUserDecision());
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print("Fetching user role...");
  String decision = await fetchUserDecision();
  print('The user decision is: $decision');
  print("Done");
}
```

and also this

```dart
import 'dart:async';

String setUserDecision() {
    return  'Yes'; 
}

Future<String> fetchUserDecision() async {
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), setUserDecision() as FutureOr<String> Function()?);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print("Fetching user role...");
  String decision = await fetchUserDecision();
  print('The user decision is: $decision');
  print("Done");
}
```

with this error

```
_CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type '(() => FutureOr<String>)?' in type cast)
```

The only solution that seems to work is this

```dart
Future<String> fetchUserDecision() async {
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    return 'Yes'; 
});
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print("Fetching user role...");
  String decision = await fetchUserDecision();
  print('The user decision is: $decision');
  print("Done");
}
```

but I would like to better understand the type of error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling your `setUserDecision()` function and takes the result of this and sends to `Future.delayed` which expect a function. Since the result of calling `setUserDecision()` is a `String`, you end up providing a `String` instead of a `Function` which makes Dart complain.

You should do this instead:

```dart
Future<String> fetchUserDecision() async {
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), setUserDecision);
}
```

Notice I have removed the `()` after `setUserDecision`. Now we provide the function as a function instead of calling it.

Comment: Thanks, it works. How could I do if I wanted to pass a function with one parameter? For example if I had setUserDecision(String userDecision)

Comment: @Cata You would then provide a method that calls your method with the argument you want. The easiest way is to use the shorthand `() =>` so your method would then become: `Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () => setUserDecision('Something'))`